# Questions about total bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sin(x)$ on $x \in[0,2\pi]$.  Find two increasing functions $h$ and $g$ such that $f=g-h$ on $x \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Finding the explicit example is where I'm stuck.  Since this is a bounded function of finite tototal variation I know an explicit $h$ and $g$ exists.  I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $g$ can be any function for which $g'$ is large enough.

Comment: I don't think I follow.

Comment: @emka: If $f=g-h$, then $g'=f\,'+h'$; $|f\,'|$ is bounded, so if you take $h'$ big enough, you can ensure that both $g'$ and $h'$ are positive. What do you know about a function with a positive derivative?

Comment: A function of positive derivative is increasing.  Could I take something simple and friendly like f(x)=x?

Comment: You mean $g(x) = x$.  Yes you can (though you might prefer $2x$).